# Apache-style logging with Heroku + Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

How do I get Apache-style server logs with Heroku? I'm using Rails on the Cedar stack.

"Apache-style" meaning, I'd like to see each individual HTTP request like this (I don't actually care if the format is exactly like Apache's):

```
66.249.71.85 - - [22/Jan/2012:15:15:04 +0000] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 200 149 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
```

I considered using a Rack-middleware logger like [Clogger](http://clogger.rubyforge.org/), but I'm not sure if there is an easy way to get the log files off the (ephemeral) dynos to a central (permanent) storage location.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Heroku supports **syslog drains**, so you can just set one up to push requests to another location and read them there.

You can read more about syslog drains **[here](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#syslog_drains)** in their documentation.

Answer (score 0):

While this post might not answer your question of getting the logs out of Heroku, this question was one of the few hits that came up when searching for a better logging in Heroku that provides the referer URL and user agent of requests.

Therefore I want to share how I accomplished to get a apache log style logging in Heroku in case someone else searches for it.

In *config.ru*:

```
require 'clogger'
use Clogger, logger: $stdout,
  format: %Q|$ip - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" status $response_length "$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"|
```

There is actually a *format: :Combined*, but this does specifically not work with Heroku since it relays through AWS and you always end up seeing an IP from the 10/8 network.

The solution above is based on the internal clogger definition for *:Combined*.

This solution has one flaw: I have seen "*ip1, ip2*" for *$ip* once from a corporate network (probably a filter/proxy behind another proxy/filter).
I didn't want to dig deeper into since my solution works for my cause, but might fail if you put this data into a log analyzer.